# If the height of the cylinder is $4$ times of its circumference what is the volume of cylinder in terms of circumference?

Tags: geometry, volume

If the height of the cylinder is $4$ times of its circumference what is the volume of cylinder in terms of circumference?

a). $\dfrac {C^3}{\pi}$

b). $\dfrac {2C^3}{\pi}$

c). $\dfrac {2C^2}{\pi^2}$

d). $\dfrac {\pi h^2}{4}$

My Attempt:

$$h=4C$$
Now,
Volume$=\pi r^2 h$
$$=\pi r^2 C$$.
??

Answer (score 0):

The circumference of the cylinder is given by $C= 2 \pi r$. From this we can write $r= \frac C{2 \pi }$.

Now, substitute $h=4C$ and $r= \frac C{2 \pi }$ into the volume expression 
$V= \pi r^2 h$ to obtain the required expression.